# How to add an if/else to an "except" statement in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

I wanted to add an if/else to an except statement that checks for a specific input by the user (i.e "exit"). However the except statement is bound to Value Error. Running the below code gives me 2 error: Value Error and Name Error. The "user_guess" variable is not being identified in the except block, hence the Name error. I've tried using abstraction, i.e routing the data via a function called from the except statements block, however I still keep getting Name Error.

```
while (lives>0 and not found): 

    try:
        user_guess=int(input(f"(Lives = {lives})Enter Your Guess: ").strip())

    except ValueError:
        if(user_guess == "exit"):
            break
        else:
            raise (ValueError)

    else:

        if((user_guess)>guess):
            print("Your guess is High. Try Something Lower. \n")
            lives-=1
```

I would like to know how to implement the code such that the program throws the "Value Error" exception to all cases other than the one case i.e when the user inputs the word "exit" into  the terminal. I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: Initilize `user_guess` above `try`!

Comment: The user_guess is checked every time for a valid input till the user runs out of lives (i.e 5 times) or if the user has guessed the number. Initializing it above 'try' would simply make the except statement illogical. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Think about this, if an error occurs during `user_guess=int(...` line, then `user_guess` is not initialized, no such variable with that name exists. Then your `except` block tries to compare "exit" to a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: move the stuff under else into the try block

Comment: @SweeneyTodd Your explanation makes perfect sense. However moving the if/else block into 'try' poses another problem. I am obtaining the value as an "int" but checking for a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you are trying to convert the input to integer as soon as you get it. Because of this you don't have an opportunity to compare it to "exit". So, instead, let us get and save the input as string, compare it to "exit", then try to convert it to an integer:

```
lives = 5
guess = 6
found = False
while lives > 0 and not found:
    user_guess = input(f"(Lives = {lives})Enter Your Guess: ").strip()
    if user_guess == "exit":
        break
    try:
        user_guess_int = int(user_guess)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input!")
    else:
        if user_guess_int > guess:
            print("Your guess is High. Try Something Lower.")
            lives -= 1
        elif user_guess_int < guess:
            print("Your guess is Low. Try Something Higher.")
            lives -= 1
        else:
            print("Correct!")
            found = True
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks a Million for your Help!